# "be forbidden to Verb" or "be forbidden from Verb_ing"

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice, infinitives, licensing

> 1.Long ago, women were forbidden to vote in political elections.
>
> 2.Long ago, women were forbidden from voting in political elections.

Which's true? **"be forbidden to V"** or **"be forbidden from V_ing"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a learner, I want to share my thoughts:

I think both pattern, using preposition "from" and "to+infinitive", are correct 
since I know we can say ([source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forbid)):

> my doctor has forbidden me to eat sugar
>
> I was forbidden from seeing him again

In order to check them, I think Ngram results would be helpful:
[image]

Thus, it seems in the case of your sentences, the pattern using to+infinitive is more common.